# a href not clickable in the right area

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("../images/ITWorld.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 22px;
}

#navbar {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

.listitem {
    padding: 7px;
    display: inline;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.reference {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#overviewpara {
    width: 800px;
}

.referenceli {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="referenceli"><a class="reference" href="http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/careersintechnology/p/ITDefinition.htm">http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/careersintechnology/p/ITDefinition.htm</a></li>
    <li class="referenceli"><a class="reference" href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/higher-education-network/2011/sep/05/top-100-universities-world-computer-science-and-information-systems-2011">http://www.guardian.co.uk/higher-education-network/2011/sep/05/top-100-universities-world-computer-science-and-information-systems-2011</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that when i hover over my hyperlinks on my references page they do not react in the correct areas. For example I'll be link 5px above the link and it will not higligh or i will be right over the link, but it will not work. Sorry for messy html.

Comment: What does "For example I'll be link 5px above the link..." mean?

Comment: I think the padding on `reference` and `referenceli` is causing the problem. create a fiddle

Comment: You have top and bottom padding 50px on your links. This is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the padding on your a tag 5px, and not your list item.

```
.referenceli {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

should be

```
.reference {
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
```

Also remove the 50px padding from the a tags: You will be better of applying that size(50px) to the margin of the list items:

```
.reference {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

should be

```
.reference {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 5px; /*So you will have a hover effect 5px below and above the link*/
}

.referenceli {

    margin: 50px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I found out that the problem was the 50px padding a little before you responded. Since this is the first answer and not comment though I'll give you the best answer.

Comment: thanks mate...Just remember, if you ever apply a hover affect on a links, apply your padding (the area you want to hover over) to the a tag and not its parent li element, or whatever parent element it has

Answer (score 1):

Changed paddings top and bottom to 5px:

```
.reference {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/uNpbk/

Answer (score 0):

Changed paddings top and bottom to 5px:

```
.reference 
{
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. I think that you need to style div and not the li tags. I added some borders to the reference and referenceli. Add the borders to your code to see your styling impact.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("../images/ITWorld.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 22px;
}

#navbar {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

.listitem {
    padding: 7px;
    display: inline;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.reference {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    border:green solid 1px;
}

#overviewpara {
    width: 800px;
}

div.referenceli{
   padding:20px 0 0 0;
   border:red 1px solid;
}
</style>
<ul>
  <div class="referenceli"><!--USE DIV TO FOCUS CSS -->
    <li><a class="reference" href="http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/careersintechnology/p/ITDefinition.htm">http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/careersintechnology/p/ITDefinition.htm
    </a></li><!-- END LI -->
  </div><!-- END REFERENCELI -->
  <div class="referenceli">
    <li><a class="reference" href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/higher-education-network/2011/sep/05/top-100-universities-world-computer-science-and-information-systems-2011">http://www.guardian.co.uk/higher-education-network/2011/sep/05/top-100-universities-world-computer-science-and-information-systems-2011
    </a></li><!-- END LI -->
  </div><!-- END REFERENCELI -->
</body>
</html>
```